# Is it possible to delete (or make private) my chat history?

Tags: support, chat

I'm wondering if there are any privacy controls or any ability to remove or hide my chat transcripts from being publicly visible.

For example, anyone may visit your profile at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/id/name and browse the chat transcripts of various chats I've had.

I understand if you visit and contribute to a public chat it would be publicly accessible, but I'm surprised I have no privacy controls if I decide I want to remove these from being publicly accessible.

Comment: If you make your chat contributions private, what do you expect people to see when they view a transcript of the channel?

Comment: @Sparr I suppose it might look as if someone were talking to themselves  :)  That's a good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By design, most information on SO is difficult to delete, so that people can't go around removing valuable content, even if they're the one that contributed it.

What you *can* do, for most any content, is to disassociate it with your account.  You can [contact the SE team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact/other) if you would like to have a particular chat transcript disassociated from your account.